# Find maximum length of an nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have an array with nodes and edges inside edges each one of them has source, target, array of officers and I would want to create a scale of lengths of officer arrays.

```
  var officersScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                        .domain([1,  d3.max(dataset.edges.officers.length, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
                                        .range([1,10]);
```

How the array looks like:

```
var dataset = {"nodes":[{"name":"Anglo American plc"},{"name":"Associated British Foods plc"},{"name":"Admiral Group plc"},{"name":"ARM Holdings plc"},{"name":"Aviva plc"},{"name":"BAE Systems plc"},{"name":"Barclays PLC"},{"name":"British American Tobacco p.l.c."},{"name":"The Berkeley Group Holdings plc"},{"name":"BHP Billiton plc"},{"name":"BP p.l.c."},{"name":"BT Group plc"},{"name":"Centrica plc"},{"name":"Compass Group PLC"},{"name":"Direct Line Insurance Group PLC"},{"name":"easyJet plc"},{"name":"International Consolidated Airlines Group, S.A."},{"name":"3i Group plc"},{"name":"Intertek Group plc"},{"name":"Lloyds Banking Group plc"},{"name":"Merlin Entertainments plc"},{"name":"Pearson plc"},{"name":"Reckitt Benckiser Group plc"},{"name":"Royal Dutch Shell plc"},{"name":"Rexam PLC"},{"name":"Rio Tinto plc"},{"name":"SABMiller plc"},{"name":"Schroders plc"},{"name":"Standard Life plc"},{"name":"SSE plc"},{"name":"Standard Chartered PLC"},{"name":"Tesco PLC"},{"name":"Whitbread PLC"}],"edges":[{"source":0,"target":29,"officers":["MEDORI, Rene"]},{"source":0,"target":30,"officers":["GROTE, Byron Elmer"]},{"source":0,"target":31,"officers":["GROTE, Byron Elmer"]},{"source":1,"target":13,"officers":["BASON, John George"]}]};
```

Comment: The *array* is not an array, but an object, and it is malformed. The parts with `,"MOYO, Dambisa Felicia, Dr"]},` and `",officers":["GODBEHERE, Ann Frances, M"]},` make the JSON invalid.

Comment: @trincot that is my bad the object is fine I just deleted some of the data to not post a huge object here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firsth thing first, your data is not valid. Invalid tokens are there, some internal objects have missing `{` etc.

However, you can loop through all officers arrays and then find max length. I hope you know how to create scale, that is for you.

```
var edges = [{"source":0,"target":29,"officers":["MEDORI, Rene"]},
           {"source":6,"target":28,"officers":["GILLIES, Crawford Scott","GRIMSTONE, Gerald Edgar, Sir"]},
           {"source":9,"target":10,"officers":["ANDERSON, Paul Milton"]},
           {"source":9,"target":19,"officers":["FREW, Anita Margaret"]},
           {"source":9,"target":23,"officers":["BRINDED, Malcolm Arthur"]},
           {"source":15,"target":32,"officers":["KENNEDY, Christopher John"]},
           {"source":24,"target":31,"officers":["CHAMBERS, Stuart John"]},
           {"source":28,"target":29,"officers":["GILLIES, Crawford Scott"]},
           "source":30,"target":31,"officers":["GROTE, Byron Elmer"]}];
```

Using `d3.max`

```
var maxlength = d3.max(edges, function(d) { return d.officers.length; })
```

Using simple `Array.prototype.map` and `Math.max`

```
var lengths = edges.map(function(edge){
     return edge.officers.length;
});

console.log(lengths);
var maxLength = Math.max(...lengths);

console.log(maxLength);
```

In single step, `ES6`

```
maxLength = Math.max(...edges.map(edge=> edge.officers.length));
```

Comment: isn't there a way to achieve that using d3.max?

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope this is what you are asking